# How do I respond to windows store review?

Tags: windows-8

I have a windows store app and reviewer indicated that app not working (crashing). I need to find which hardware he is using and other info. What options I have to get more information about this crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much you can do, first of all you have provided support email in app description during the app submission process, that could be used by users. Second you can write your own review and in it respond to the error or ask for more details. It's also a good idea to add your email/Twitter/Facebook link in the app as well, so it's not hard for users to contact you with their feedback.
The last resort is probably gathering the error report from Windows Store about your app and finding the error in it, this is described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/27/improving-apps-with-quality-reports.aspx